# Cmake linking error CLion

Tags: c++, cmake

I am making a Nana Project but when I Try to link with CMake in CLion i get a maybe bug
This is my Cmake file

```
project(nanaGUI)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.9)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
set(NANA_INCLUDE nana)
set(NANA_FILESYSTEM_FORCE 1)
set(NANA_LIBRARY_D libnana_d.a)
include_directories(Include)
add_executable(nanaGUI ${SOURCE_FILES})
#add_library(NANA_LIBRARY_D libnana_d.a)
#set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -l libnana_d.a )
target_link_libraries(nanaGUI "${NANA_LIBRARY_D}")
```

and I get this error

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\arllk\CLionProjects\nanaGUI\cmake-build-debug --target nanaGUI -- -j 2
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/nanaGUI.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable nanaGUI.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibnana_d
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\nanaGUI.dir\build.make:97: nanaGUI.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/nanaGUI.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/nanaGUI.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: nanaGUI] Error 2
```

I see that the fault is in

> cannot find **-llibnana_d**

but i cant se a way to avoid **-l** to join the name of **libnana_d**

Comment: There appears to be a `FindNana` so you should be able to use `cmake`'s `find_package()` to do the hard work for you https://github.com/temporaer/hancock_real/blob/master/CMakeModules/FindNana.cmake and also https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries